# Adding className or class prop does not result in adding its value to the class property of react tooltip div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-tooltip

I am trying to use react-tooltip library to add tooltips functionality to my application. The problem I have encountered is that passing `className` or `class` prop does not result in `class` property added to the corresponding `div` element. After quite some time studying the library code and debugging I still have no idea why it is not being added. Seems like a bug in the library (I have posted a bug report [here](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/726)), but I am not ruling out the possibility of me overlooking something, therefore posting here as well.

Version of react-tooltip: `4.2.21`

React code:

```
// App.js
useEffect(() => {
    ReactTooltip.rebuild()
}, [])

// MyTooltip.js
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import classes from './MyTooltip.module.css';

const MyTooltip = (props) => 
  <React.Fragment>
    {
      ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div>
          <div className={classes.backdrop} />
          <ReactTooltip
            id={props.id}
            type="dark"
            place={props.place}
            className={classes.tooltip}
          >
            <span>{props.text}</span>
          </ReactTooltip>
        </div>
      ,
      document.getElementById("tooltip")
    )}
  </React.Fragment>

export default MyTooltip;
```

HTML generated: `<div class="__react_component_tooltip t724ff40a-5699-4bf1-9fd7-7295f4f8e414 place-bottom type-dark" data-id="tooltip"><span>Test tooltip</span></div>`

Thanks in advance for any tips that would help to resolve this problem.

Comment: How do you generate the `classes` object? Also, may it just be that `react-tooltip` doesn't include a `className` prop?

Comment: thanks for your feedback, since the problem was not solved by my answer, I removed it. hope to get the right answer soon, best regards.